# Unable to resolve "[Location]" from "[File]"

Tags: react-native, expo

When I create index.js in my src/screens directory I get the following `Unable to resolve "./bottomTabs/AddEvent" from "src\screens\index.js"`. When I check that my src/screens/bottomTabs/AddEvent wasn't exporting anything other than what I was expecting. This is the code in my index.js in src/screens `export { default as Add } from "./bottomTabs/Add";`

This is my Add.js file

```
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";

const Add = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Add</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Add;
```

I don't have any problems with any of the other files from that location, just that one & I'm all kinds of stumped as to why. Can anyone explain why this is happening or point me in the direction to get the information myself?

For this project, I'm using `"react-native": "0.71.6"` & `"expo": "^48.0.7"` if that helps.